# Open GitHub repo in VS Code with a live test server? I.e. view changes as I make them on a live server before committing them to the main branch

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-pages

I am using the GitHub repo integration in VS Code for version control. It's really easy to code in the editor and track and push changes to the GitHub repo from there.

What I am missing is the live server view. When working from a regular folder (i.e. non-Github repo) in VS Code, the live server is a must-have for me.

Is there any way to have a live server or live view connected to non-committed changes I am making in the GitHub repo from VS Code?

The reason I would like this is because I have some users on my GitHub Pages and I don't want to impact their experience when an update doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to push something to GitHub to see your changes in your browser! Your testing environment could be anything. You don't have to use GitHub Pages for that. If you're working on a simpele HTML, JS, CSS project, you could just open the index.html file in your browser.

What kind of project are you working on?
Have you tried the Live Server extension for VS Code?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Comment: Hi Annelies, yes I am using that extension, however I don't think it works for a remote Github repo. Normally I would just left click my file and select 'open with live browser' or something similar. But working from the remote repo that option isn't there. I am working on upgrading this: https://bassieee.github.io/test.ficka/

Comment: I'm a bit new to this, perhaps my idea for how I test things and then push it 'live' is not the best. My plan is: change things in the remote repo from VS Code, test with some kind of local server/in my own browser, review code, commit and push to the GitHub Pages I linked to above.